# How to find \$R_{eq}\$ in this situation?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

[image]

I am having difficulties understanding where a parallel resistor situation is occurring in order to help me find \$R_{eq}\$.

My first thought was that \$v_{ab} = v_{ac}\$, but that would mean \$v_{bc} = 0\$ which is not correct.

Does anyone have any tips for how to think/approach this problem?

Comment: Have you noticed that Vb is directly connected to Vd? How does that help you redraw?

Comment: would the 2 12K resistors be in parallel then? since vb = vd?

Comment: Yes, they are in parallel.

Comment: The most important thing with reading circuits is to believe what your eyes tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical exercise to solve by inspection, but once you find the "disturbing" element.

In this case the disturbing component is the 4k resistor, so please, think about temporarily detaching it from the circuit.

After that, you can see that the two 12k resistors are in parallel and in series to the 6k resistor for a total of 12k.

Now, attach again the 4k resistor (which results in parallel to what you previously found), and finally obtain 4//12 = 3k.

Comment: Please don't hand out answers to obvious homework/exam problems.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson - OK, I agree, even if besides the solution, I indicated one of the possible methodologies, too, which is the most important part, in my opinion...

Comment: Thanks for your help, this response did offer a correct idea. I am only trying to practice this concept, and I needed clarification.